# Saving changes in xml file in the server

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a web page which correctly load an xml file into DOM and use that information to create a table on the html with javascript, now I want to create an admin page where you can change the xml file content easily for every person but i don't know which tool, library or function I can use to create a xml document back from de DOM and save change in the server.
How can I do that?
**Edit:** This is actually a small list so if you can figure out a better way to do which is not with xml please tell
Thanks

Comment: so you want to be able to edit the XML data basically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage the data that is in the XML file I would use PHP and the simpleXML object to store the data, then output a form using foreach() to loop through each element in the XML and put the data into a bunch of inputs like `<input type="text" value="<?php //output data here ?>" >`. Then you can allow the user to edit the fields, hit a Save button, delete the old XML file and basically just save the newly edited one wherever you want.

Comment: Well I wanted a javascript solution since I'm not really familiarized with PHP but I may be this is a great opportunity to start learning it, thanks for the answer

Comment: You could use javascript, but I personally believe PHP would be much simpler when it came to dynamically altering the data. The javascript version would make the changing and saving of the data pretty complex